# The float does not work well

Tags: html, css

i have a problem here with flow , why the left cloumn doesn't flow around the right cloumn
[image]

the right column html code :

```html
    <div id="sidebar">
      <p class="beanheading">
        <img src="images/bag.gif" alt="Bean Machine bag" />
        <br />
        ORDER ONLINE
        with the 
        <a href="form.html">BEAN MACHINE</a>
        <br />
        <span class="slogan">
            FAST <br />
            FRESH <br />
            TO YOUR DOOR <br />
        </span>
      </p>
      <p>
        Why wait?  You can order all our fine coffees right from the Internet with our new, 
        automated Bean Machine.  How does it work?  Just click on the Bean Machine link, 
        enter your order, and behind the scenes, your coffee is roasted, ground 
        (if you want), packaged, and shipped to your door.
      </p>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
```

the right column css code :

```css
#sidebar {
  background:       #efe5d0 url(images/background.gif) bottom right;
  font-size:        105%;
  padding:          15px;
  margin:           0px 10px 10px 10px;
  width:            280px;
  float:            right;   
}
```

Comment: Add more details to your question. Provide code of complete page.

Comment: What do you mean by "flow around the right column" ?

Comment: this is the way i want it : http://store1.up-00.com/2016-05/1464582947761.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear but I think,

You have 2 of block contents and need arrange these content in the same row.

Following is the css for left and right blocks that is to be arranged in the same row,

```
block_left {
  width: x%;
  float: left;
  }
block_right {
  width: y%;
  }
```

Here width `x+y = 100`, based on the image you shared I think,

```
block_left {
      width: 70%;
      float: left;
      }
    block_right {
      width: 30%;
      }
```